Formula returning dynamic values from an array works in excel, but not in VBA
I'm having an issue with a formula that I wrote in excel to take a negative number in a column (in this case, M10), and find a positive number that can absorb it without going below 0. (ex. 10 + (5) = 5).
=ADDRESS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((M:M+M10>0),),0)),13)
In the worksheet, column M contains both the positive and negative numbers, and will also be updated when the formula finds a match and combines the numbers. So for example, 10 could fit (5) twice, but for a third instance of (5), the formula would return a different value/address.
The formula above works in excel however with vba I keep getting a type mismatch error. I've tried storing the result in a variable and declaring it as a String, I've tried it without the Address portion and declaring it as Long, Integer, etc.
Application.Evaluate("ADDRESS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((""M:M+"" & row1.Value & "">0""),),0)),13")
For context, row1.value is the value of the current iteration within column M, dynamically replacing M10 in the excel version.
Similar questions on SO are resolved by escaping quotations by doubling them up, which i'm already doing. Is there an issue with syntax or is there a limitation to vba for this application?
Any suggestions are much appreciated!
Sub SpreadMacro()

'Defining Variables

Dim Lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim row1 As Range
Dim Sp1 As Long
Dim Sp2 As Long
Dim Sp3 As Long
Dim Mtch As Long
Dim MtchGL As String
Dim Mx As Long
Dim rng2 As Range


'Find table length
Lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("H4:H" & Lr)


'Find negative values and set spread values
For Each row1 In rng.Rows
    If row1.Value >= 0 Then
    
        GoTo Skip

    Else
        Set rng2 = Range("M4:M" & Lr)
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng2) + row1.Value < 0 Then
            
            row1.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
            GoTo Skip
        
        Else
        
            Sp1 = row1.Offset(0, 6)
            Sp2 = row1.Offset(0, 7)
            Sp3 = row1.Offset(0, 8)
            
'Find budget value than can fit the variance, and return the cell address and account

            Debug.Print "ADDRESS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((M:M+" & row1.Value & ">0),),0)),13"
            'Debug.Print "Application.Evaluate("ADDRESS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((M:M+"" & row1.Value & "">0),),0)),13"
            MtchGL = Range(Mtch).Offset(0, -9)
            
'Insert spread values into the matched account
            Range(Mtch).Offset(0, 1).Formula = Range(Mtch).Offset(0, 1).Formula & "+" & Sp1
            Range(Mtch).Offset(0, 2).Formula = Range(Mtch).Offset(0, 2).Formula & "+" & Sp2
            Range(Mtch).Offset(0, 3).Formula = Range(Mtch).Offset(0, 3).Formula & "+" & Sp3
            
'Clear the negative variance from over budget account and indicate where the variance was spread
            row1.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Spread in " & MtchGL
            row1.Offset(0, 6).Value = "0"
            row1.Offset(0, 7).Value = "0"
            row1.Offset(0, 8).Value = "0"
            End If
    End If
    
Skip:

Next row1

End Sub


Your quotes (and parentheses) are off. Debug.Print "ADDRESS(INDEX(M:M,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((M:M+" & row1.Value & ">0),),0)),13" and inspect the output in the Immediate Window.

Thanks for the reply Ben. Debug.Print is returning the same type mismatch error as the original post.

What does Debug.Print VarType(row1.Value) return to the Immediate Window?

Btw For Each row1 In rng.Rows can be simplified to For Each row1 In rng

Edited the OP with the entire code. I've successfully referred to row1 in a single iteration with other pieces of the code so I thought it would work here as well. I've also tried defining the row1.value as a variable and using that instead but that hasn't worked either.

Another help would be Debug.Print row1.Address

Debug.Print VarType(row1.Value) returned a mix of 5 and 0, some rows have no number.

You should likely handle the case of an empty row. Or, use row1.Address instead of .Value.

Not the most elegant solution but I just passed the excel formula into a cell, stored the string output in a variable and converted it to a range.
